How I can change a Tabbar icon Background color when it select?
This is i want to setwhen tab is select or I want to try when the user select a tab from the tab bar at that time i want to change selected tab cion background color.
Tab( text: StringConstant.cricketTitle, icon: Icon(Icons.sports_cricket_outlined,color: Colors.white,),),
const TabBar(
dividerHeight: 0,
padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
indicatorColor: Colors.white,
indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
automaticIndicatorColorAdjustment: false,
unselectedLabelStyle:const TextStyle(color: white40,),
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              text: StringConstant.cricketTitle,
              icon: Icon(Icons
                  .sports_cricket_outlined,) /*ImageIcon(AssetImage(ImagePathConstant.cricketImage))*/,
            ),
            Tab(
              text: StringConstant.footBallTitle,
              icon: Icon(Icons
                  .sports_soccer) /*ImageIcon(AssetImage(ImagePathConstant.footBallImage))*/,
            ),
            Tab(
              text: StringConstant.kabaddiTitle,
              icon: Icon(Icons
                  .sports_kabaddi_outlined) /*ImageIcon(AssetImage(ImagePathConstant.kabbadiImage))*/,
            ),
            Tab(
              text: StringConstant.basketBallTitle,
              icon: Icon(Icons
                  .sports_basketball_outlined) /* ImageIcon(AssetImage(ImagePathConstant.basketBallImage))*/,
            ),
            Tab(
              text: StringConstant.volleyBallTitle,
              icon: Icon(Icons
                  .sports_volleyball_outlined) /* ImageIcon(AssetImage(ImagePathConstant.volleyBallImage))*/,
            ),
          ])


Please provide TabBar code you have implemented.

check it i add tab bar code into the questions

Try to add indicatorColor: Colors.blue, // Set your desired indicator color here
in TabBar.

check i add images @DroidFlutter

Try added code below.

Thank you for the answer @DroidFlutter but i use tab controller and create a custome tab like this
Column(
children: [
Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: index == tabController.index
? selectBackgroundColor
: unSelectBackgroundColor ?? Colors.transparent,
shape: BoxShape.circle),
child: icon,
),
],
),

You can use same logic as posted in my code for change icon background color or change whole icon image as your need while tab is selected. Like...
Icon(_selectedIndex == 0?Icons.home:Icons.selectedHomeIcon)

yes it veryuse full & Working.

int _selectedIndex = 0;

In TabBar take onTap method as
onTap: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = value;
                  });
                },

And check tab icon color like below
Icon(Icons.home, color: _selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.black)

